# Размещение в памяти char* foo и char foo[]

Tags: c

Недавно услышал, что в Си: `char* foo = "bar";` и `char foo[] = "bar";` - не одно и то же, насколько это корректно? Мне сказали, что указатель на char лежит в text сегменте и является read-only, а массив char лежит в стеке, вызванной функции. Я думал, что компилятор преобразует массив в указатель по формуле - *(foo + n)

Comment: *`"...не одно и то же, насколько это корректно?"`* -- зависит от контекста, в котором вы используете `char* foo` и `char foo[]`. Однако, в том, *`"что указатель на char лежит в text сегменте и является read-only"`* вас обманули, там располагаются символы (константы), которые **может** адресовать указатель

Comment: @avp А строка в Си будет преобразовываться в константу, на которую будет указывать указатель?

Comment: @avp точнее в констатный массив, на первый элемент которого будет указывать указатель.

Comment: Вопрос бессмыслен вне контекста. В С есть контексты, в которых `char *` и `char []` - одно и то же. А есть контексты в которых - не одно и то же.

Comment: @kaylil_01, в таком контексте `void f1(char *foo, char [] bar) { ... }` это одно и то же, а вот в таком `void f2() {char *foo = "123"; char bar[] = "123"; ... f1(foo, bar); ...}` разница есть. Под сам указатель  `foo` будет выделена память (4 байта в 32-бит и 8 байт в 64-бит системах)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это действительно не одно и то же.
Массив - это набор элементов, последовательно расположенных в памяти. 
То есть когда вы пишите

```
    void Do(void)
    {
        char foo[3] = {'1', '2', '3'};
    }
```

то на стеке функции выделяется место для трех элементов типа char. То есть

```
   &foo[0] ( равносильно foo )
   &foo[1] ( равносильно (foo+1) )
   ...
```

будут на стеке данной функции.

Если же сделать так

```
    void Do(void)
    {
        char *foo = "123";
    }
```

то адреса каждого отдельного элемента точно не будут на стеке функции, а будут где-то, где решит компилятор. При этом все равно верно, что foo указывает на '1', а (foo + 1) на '2'.

Это важно в случае, как уже написали выше, когда вы пытаетесь что-то редактировать, а также когда вы, например, хотите вернуть указатель.

```
    char* Do(void)
    {
        char foo[3] = {'1', '2', '3'};
        return foo;
    }
```

Такой возврат вызовет проблему, потому что вы вернете что-то, что было на стеке функции, и условно говоря при последующем использовании вы вообще не знаете, что там будет лежать.

А если вернуть так

```
    char* Do(void)
    {
        char* foo = "123";
        return foo;
    }
```

то никаких проблем. Указатель показывает на место, где лежит константа. И она там и останется.

Кроме этого вы никак не можете сделать так, чтобы массив, объявленный таким образом

```
    char foo[3];
```

был создан на куче.

Answer (score 1):

Я дукмаю, вы имеете ввиду записи

```
char * foo = "bar";
```

и

```
char foo[] = "bar";
```

Если таки да - то в первом случае вы имеете указатель на константный массив символов, расположенный где-то, может даже в r/o памяти, а во втором - обычный массив символов в стеке для локальной переменной и в сегменте данных или гд там - точно не помню - для глобальных. Главное, что это будут вполне изменяемые данные.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что это происходит из-за того, что в случае с указателем: сначала создается строка(например в data сегменте) и только потом для нее создают указатель, а во втором случае, мы явно объявили хранилище, и так как мы находимся в функции, то строка сохранится на стеке?

Comment: Во втором случае строка - инициализатор для массива, так что создается массив, и заполняется указанными буквами. А в первом - просто создается указатель.

Answer (score 1):

Просто это разные типы, вообще, и дело тут не в том, где размещаются данные.

То есть:

```
char *p1 = "aaa"; // p1 — указатель на область памяти. И всё.
char p2[] = "aaa"; // p2 — массив, состоящий из указателя и размера.
```

Для проверки:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main() {
    char d1[100] = "aaa";
    printf( "%zu\r\n", sizeof(d1) ) ; // 100
 
    char *d2 = "aaa";
    printf( "%zu\r\n", sizeof(d2) ) ; // 8
 
    return 0;
}
```

Другое дело, что функции, обычно, принимают именно указатель. А, например, если взять C++ и шаблонные параметры, то можно и явно увидеть, как компилятор очень даже различает указатель и массив. Например:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> int f() ;

template<>
int f<char*>(){
    return 1;
}

template<>
int f<char [100]>(){
    return 2;
}

int main() {
    char d1[100] = "aaa";
    std::cout << f<decltype(d1)>() << std::endl; // 2
    
    char *d2 = "aaa";
    std::cout << f<decltype(d2)>() << std::endl; // 1
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В C это тоже разные типы. И зачем примеры кода на C++ в вопросе с меткой [tag:c]?

Comment: Для демонстрации, что с точки зрения компилятора обе эти записи не очень синонимы. Пример на C++ это лучше показывает, просто.

Comment: Непонятно, почему пример в тему, если он написан на языке, который в данном топике не не по теме.

Comment: На сколько я знаю, на C не получится продемонстрировать, что компилятор считает эти типы разными. А C++, всё-таки, родственный язык с несколько более широкими возможностями, и по вопросу пример на нём наглядно показывает, что для компилятора эти две записи не синонимы. Просто, использовал его тут, как инструмент, демонстрирующий этот факт, не более.

Comment: Ваш первый пример можно переписать на C и он показывает разницу

Comment: Привёл ответ ближе к теме.

Comment: Оператор `sizeof` возвращает значение типа `size_t`, следовательно в качестве спецификатора типа в функцию `printf` следует передавать `%zu`, а не `%d`.

Comment: Да, согласен. Исправил, спасибо.